# Date conversion in hive, month wrong

Tags: date, hive

I have a date column in my text file in mm-DD-yy format (e.g. 02-5-16). I am trying to convert it into date. First I loaded this date column as a string into a hive table, then tried like this.

```
Create table sales (empid int, saledate string, item string, qty int, saleamt int, incperc int) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
LOAD data inpath '/user/Srini/Empsales.csv' into table sales;


select saledate, unix_timestamp(saledate, 'mm-DD-yy'), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(saledate, 'mm-DD-yy')) from sales;
```

**Output:
**02-5-16** 1451932320      **2016-01-05** 00:02:00**

I was expecting the output of 1st column and last column to match, at least the date part.
i.e. if my sale date is "02-5-16", I was expecting 2016-02-05. But not. I am getting the year and day parts correctly. Month is wrong. Could you please help on this?

Comment: Quoting the Java documentation: **m  minute** in hour - **M month** in year - **D day in _year_** - the **number of symbol letters** you specify also determines the format. The actual date format for your example should be `MM-d-yy` - or maybe you were just experimenting random letters??

Comment: The Hive documentation for `unix_timestamp` has a link to the Java documentation > http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html